# Nginx status endpoint running inside Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, endpoint

I'm new to Nginx, which I'm running in a Docker container to serve a simple website. I want to add an `/health` endpoint that simply returns status 200 + some arbitrary content.

I copied and adjusted the standard `nginx.conf` from `/etc/nginx/` by adding

```
server {
    location /health {
        return 200 "alive";
    }
}
```

at the bottom inside the `http` block. But when I run the Docker, and try to access `localhost/health`, I just get `no such file or directory`. Accessing the website at `localhost` works fine.

I also tried copying other code blocks, e.g., this one: https://gist.github.com/dhrrgn/8650077
But then I get `conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`.

Am I placing the `location` at a wrong location inside `nginx.conf`? Do I need some special server configuration? What's the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was with my Nginx Docker setup/configuration: I am using `nginx:alpine`, which has the configuration files at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. There, `default.conf` defines the default configuration of Nginx. So, I had to remove `default.conf` and copy my configuration there instead. In the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Of course, I also had to define the standard route in `nginx.conf` then:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /health {
        return 200 'alive';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }
}
```

Comment: So we can't add /health in default.conf ?

Comment: @Learner I don't think we can - I just went through this, and had to remove the `default.conf` before my custom nginx config would work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it in one line without building an image, you can just do the following:

**#1 Create Nginx.conf file**

```
nano /tmp/nginx-tester/nginx.conf
```

and put the following content there:

```
events {}

http {
   server {
       location / {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
   
       location /health {
           return 200 '{"status":"UP"}';
           add_header Content-Type application/json;
       }
   }
}
```

If you see, all what it's doing is to serve a http status 200 with a json stating the status is `UP`

**#2 Run the NgInx Image**

Just to have it in one line, and avoid keep recreating the image each time, you can just specify a volume like this:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8077:80 --name nginx-tester -v /tmp/nginx-tester/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx
```

- `-it`: interactive processes (like a shell)
- `--rm`: the container is removed when it exits
- `-p 8077:80`: hostPort:containerPort
- `--name`: Name of the Container
- `-v`: Bind mount a volume (fileHost:fileContainer:ReadOnly)
- `nginx`: Image that will be downloaded and ran

**#3 Test it**

You can do it just by going to the `server`:`8077` *(Which was the port you specified at the step `#2`)*

```
~ > curl http://myserver:8077/health
{"status":"UP"}
```

This way you can change the config file, and by just doing a:

```
docker restart nginx-tester
```

You are able to reload the file without the need of rebuilding the image.